# Rosserial arduino: How to check on device if in sync with host?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to check on a device if it is still in sync with the the host pc which is connected via rosserial_python serial_node.py?

The problem is that the device keeps on doing what it was told to last before loosing sync. Is it possible to check on device if it is in sync or is setting up my own watch dog the strait forward solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124481/rosserial-arduino:-how-to-check-on-device-if-in-sync-with-host?/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can query the NodeHandle using the "connected" function:

```
  if (nh.connected())
  {
     // do something here
  }
```

It returns a bool as to whether the connection is still active, but be aware there is a timeout before we "break" the connection.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1